# Will mineral oil help prevent smelly basement traps during extended vacations?

Tags: basement, drain

Will mineral oil in my basement traps keep them from smelling during a NY winter while we vacation elsewhere for three months?  Our remodeled basement has had a problem with the odor, which is fine if we keep running water periodically.  The drains are in a Kohler jetted tub and toilet, a kitchenette with small sink, and an unused sink in the storage area.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A very interesting idea, but note that bulk mineral oil down a drain may be against The Rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. RV antifreeze ([propylene glycol](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/ToxProfiles/tp189.pdf)) is also said to work well. Anything that doesn't evaporate, doesn't rot, and isn't damaging to the plumbing or the environment will do. You could also stop them with rubber mats, test plugs, or rags, as appropriate.

Comment: In many ways RV antifreeze would be better. If the drains have a suitable shape (more likely for tub or utility sink) a expandable test plug might work.

Comment: FYI [propylene glycol](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/ToxProfiles/tp189.pdf)